# Retornar valor em Json com angular 2

Tags: json, rest, angular

Estou trabalhando em um projeto aonde preciso retornar um valor do banco de dados que é pego via REST em formato json. O front-end do projeto é em angular 2.

Tenho uma tabela de trabalhadores e preciso que quando o usuario clique no botão de editar, ele ja traga os valores do banco de dados nas labels.

Sou iniciante em angular 2.

Comment: E qual é o erro da tua implementação? Qual é o codigo que estás a usar que está a dar erro?

Comment: Não aponta erro :s

Comment: @LeticiaFatima, sua pergunta está muito ampla. Sugeriria que a reformulasse. Dê uma lida [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente utilizar o ReactiveForms do Angular junto com o FormGroup e seus formControls.

Basicamente você configura normalmente o form no HTML e no Typescript você define os valores, validadores e etc.

Na tabela ao clicar você deve chamar a api pelo Http do angular e associar os valores da resposta da API ao formgroup com o setValue.

Eu Criei um plunker abaixo com dados fixos para ficar mais claro, espero ter ajudado :).

http://plnkr.co/edit/fOIirV6sIRhYjjspTDQ8?p=preview